# ¿Cómo enviar correctamente una ruta de imagen correctamente del controlador a una vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy haciendo una vista dinamica en la que hay una tabla, y le mando datos desde el controlador. Me funciona casi todo perfectamente, excepto de que las imagenes que les mando no cargan las imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi estoy creando la lista y enviandolo a la vista:

```
string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\imgAndroid\", "*.jpg");      

            foreach (var img in imagenes)
            {
                string[] rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");

                string[] imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[2].Split("_");

                if (pedidoParametro != "" && pedidoParametro == imagenRecuperada[0])
                {
                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(pedidoParametro);
                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                    pedido.setimagenes(img);
                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                }
            }

            return View("Pedido", listaPedidos);
```

Asi se arma en la vista:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CUIT / DNI</th>
                    <th>Número de remito</th>
                    <th>Número de pedido</th>
                    <th>Monto</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach(var pd in Model)
                {
                 <tr>
                    <td>@pd.getCuitDni().ToString()</td>
                    <td>@pd.getNumeroRemito().ToString()</td>
                    <td>@pd.getNumeroPedido().ToString()</td>
                    <td>@pd.getMonto().ToString()</td>
                </tr>   
                }                
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <section class="galeria">
            @{int cont = 0;}
            @foreach(var pd in Model)
            {
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src='@pd.getImagenes().ToString()' data-img-mostrar="@cont"/>
                    @{
                        cont++;
                    }
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="@pd.getImagenes().ToString()" data-img-mostrar="@cont"/>
                </div>
                
                cont++;
            }            
        </section>
```

Ya intenté usando rutas relativas y absolutas pero no parece funcionar.

**EDIT CONTROLADOR COMPLETO:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Pedido(string pedidoParametro)
        {
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
            PedidoViewModel pedido = new PedidoViewModel();

            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Images\");

            string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\Images\", "*");
            string[] rutaCompleta = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.jpg");           

            foreach (var img in imagenes)
            {
                string[] rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");

                //FOREACH images --> [2] // FOREACH rutaCompleta --> [9]
                string[] imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[2].Split("_");

                if (pedidoParametro != "" && pedidoParametro == imagenRecuperada[0])
                {
                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();            
                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(pedidoParametro);
                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                    pedido.setimagenes(img);
                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                }
            }

            return View("Pedido", listaPedidos);
        }
```

Comment: En el navegador, click derecho sobre la imagen, inspeccionar elemento -> ver la ruta de donde está apuntando cada imagen actualmente.

Comment: La ruta ya use desde el disco C: (C:\...\wwwroot\imgAndroid) y tambien con ~\wwwroot\imgAndroid\[nombreDeImagen].jpg

Comment: Lee nuevamente el primer comentario. Lentamente. Por favor :)

Comment: Lo que te pregunta freddy es.. ya sabes que ruta quisiste poner.. ahora que ruta dice el navegador que esta usando?

Comment: La ruta del navegador que aparece son las dos, las rutas aparecen bien desde el inspeccionar elemento